# MySQL replacing

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have a MySQL table with a VARCHAR field called 'name' and a few thousand rows. Each row is formatted like:

'Some text <1000 - 2000>'

I would like to remove the '<1000 - 2000>' part, leaving just the 'Hello world' text. The text and numbers are different for each row. How can this be done with a query? I assume some sort of regular expression.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSTR` and `REVERSE` to get the position of the `<` character then remove it by index:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `name` = SUBSTRING( `name`, 0, INSTR( REVERSE( `name` ), `<` ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it might be what you want https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp.

Regards, Hiawatha

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
set @txt='Some text <1000 - 2000>';

select left(@txt,locate('<',@txt)-1) as text
```

## [SQl fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3872)